# Ansible shell passes a command without executing it

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I am using ansible for the execution of a script (myScript.sh) over some nodes through the command:

```
- hosts: primaryNodes,!node13
  vars:
    mongodPath: /usr/local/mongodb
  become: yes
  become_user: user
  tasks:
  - name: starting mongod on all shards
    shell: "sh {{ mongodPath }}/myScript.sh"
    register: out
  - debug: var=out.stdout_lines
```

The execution of the script may need around 2-3 seconds or maybe less in order to give an output  message on the shell (depending on the node). I am using the out.stdout_lines for debugging purposes, to be sure about the status of the execution.

Some nodes give as an output the following one which is correct;

```
ok: [node16] => {
    "out.stdout_lines": [
        "about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.", 
        "forked process: 2837", 
        "child process started successfully, parent exiting"
    ]
}
```

But some other nodes, seem to have passed the command, without executing it;

```
ok: [node2] => {
    "out.stdout_lines": []
}
```

I have managed to solve this by using the following playbook (added sleep) - all the nodes now give the desired output message (child process started successfully);

```
- hosts: primaryNodes,!node13
  vars:
    mongodPath: /usr/local/mongodb
  become: yes
  become_user: user
  tasks:
  - name: starting mongod on all shards
    shell: "sh {{ mongodPath }}/myScript.sh && sleep 5s"
    register: out
  - debug: var=out.stdout_lines
```

I know that this is a rough solution for my case, but is there a way to wait for a responding message from the node?

Comment: Why do you call `sh`? This is already run with a shell!

Comment: if you `debug: var=out` then you will see the return code and std_err, as it's possible your script failed on something else

Answer (score 0):

```
  shell: "sh {{ mongodPath }}/myScript.sh && sleep 5s"
```

This will execute *myscript.sh*, then wait for it to end, then wait 5 seconds, you could try something like:

```
  shell: "{{ mongodPath }}/myScript.sh && tail -n 10 {{ mongodPath }}/myScript.log"
```

The second command will wait for the *myScript.sh* to finish succesfully (return 0), then it will show the script log, if there is no log then your first command didn't work correctly.